# How to get the height of an element after using Foundation data-equalizer?

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make a span the same height as another div which is in the same level of its great-grandparent. Here's the structure:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  <div class="slider-left" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="slider-image-wrap" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="bx-wrapper">
      <div class="bx-viewport">
        <ul class="slider-images">
          <li>
            <img ... >
            <span class="stretch-bg">
            </span>
            ...
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the `img` tag is hidden, and the real slider image is the background of `span`. In the `.slider-left` div there are other contents, and I want to make the `span` the same height as `.slider-left`. But `$('.slider-left').height()`won't return the height of that div after data-equalizer changes it. I've tried to put that code at the very bottom of the page, but it did not work. Anyone have any idea how to do that? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried callback?

```
$(document).on('after-height-change.fndtn.equalizer', function(){
  $('.slider-left').height();
});
```

More you can find here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to use `offsetHeight` but it's working!